# KVM Bridge on Ubuntu 20.04 on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, raspberrypi, qemu, network-bridge

I cannot get networking inside a guest VM to work with KVM on a Raspberry Pi 4 8GB running the official Ubuntu 20.04 image. I have my networking configured correctly, as far as I can tell. And I'm really hoping someone will tell me I did something wrong and can point me to better documentation. I've been through netplan's docs, a dozen different tutorials on KVM setup, and have even looked at some QEMU docs related to CPU config, because I found that QEMU isn't nearly as well built out for aarch64 as it is for x86_64.

I installed KVM through the same means as I have found in a dozen tutorials:

```
$ sudo apt install qemu qemu-kvm libvirt-clients libvirt-daemon-system virtinst bridge-utils
$ sudo systemctl enable libvirtd
$ sudo systemctl start libvirtd
```

Here is my netplan:

```
$ cat /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml 
network:
    ethernets:
        eth0:
            dhcp4: false
            dhcp6: false
            optional: true
            nameservers:
                addresses: [1.1.1.1, 1.0.0.1]
    wifis:
        wlan0:
            dhcp4: true
            dhcp6: false
            optional: true
            access-points:
                "censored":
                    password: "censored"
    bridges:
        br0:
            interfaces: [eth0]
            nameservers:
                addresses: [1.1.1.1, 1.0.0.1]
            parameters:
                stp: true
                forward-delay: 4
            dhcp4: true
            dhcp6: false
    version: 2
    renderer: networkd
```

And then I defined it for the KVM domain:

```
$ sudo mkdir -p /opt/kvm
$ sudo nano /opt/kvm/host-bridge.xml

<network>
    <name>host-bridge</name>
    <forward mode="bridge"/>
    <bridge name="br0"/>
</network>

$ virsh net-define /opt/kvm/host-bridge.xml
$ virsh net-start host-bridge
$ virsh net-autostart host-bridge
```

I then checked that it's actually present and configured proper:

```
$ virsh net-list --all
 Name          State      Autostart   Persistent
--------------------------------------------------
 default       inactive   no          yes
 host-bridge   active     yes         yes
```

After starting the VM creation, I checked that its vnet0 gets added to the bridge properly:

```
$ sudo virt-install --name Test-VM --ram=2048 --vcpus=2 --cpu max --hvm --disk path=/opt/vhd/test-vhd,size=16 --cdrom /opt/iso/ubuntu-20.04.1-live-server-arm64.iso --network bridge=br0 --graphics vnc
```

```
$ virsh domiflist Test-VM
 Interface   Type     Source   Model    MAC
-----------------------------------------------------------
 vnet0       bridge   br0      virtio   52:54:00:64:58:9e
```

```
$ brctl show
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
br0             8000.dca632b43f5b       yes             eth0
                                                        vnet0
docker0         8000.0242aa58079a       no
docker1         8000.024296884d89       no              veth239b4dd
                                                        veth76e81fc
                                                        vethdffe7c7
                                                        vethef20e5a
```

However, after all of this, networking inside of my guest doesn't seem to work. It just spins and spins trying to get an IP address, but it never gets one. Is there something I've missed?

I also checked that the VM is actually using the bridged interface, and it seems like it is:

```
$ virsh edit Test-VM
...
    <interface type='bridge'>
      <mac address='52:54:00:64:58:9e'/>
      <source bridge='br0'/>
      <model type='virtio'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x01' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
    </interface>
...
```

Here's a screen of the guest just spinning. As you can see, I have full network capabilities through the bridge interface on the host to connect to KVM through VNC.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NVdm.png)

Comment: Hi @Tyrelius - I see you configured your br0 for dhcp4 in the host as well, did it get that up and an address assigned in the host? Because if not then we might maybe have an issue outside of the kvm stack. If the br0 DHCP on the host worked fine, then could you compare the logs on the dhcp server (if accessible) if the requests from the host and the guest both arrive and if they look similar or not?

Comment: And about "isn't nearly as well built out for aarch64 as it is for x86_64" I guess it is more "not as well tested". If you have any clear "if (a) would change then (b) would work" cases please file a bug at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/qemu or (if applicable to both) at https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/pkgreport.cgi?repeatmerged=no&src=qemu

Comment: br0 is taking the same MAC address as eth0, so the DHCP logs don't tell me much, except that the IP is being assigned. And br0 is working great on the host. eth0 does not get an address when I check `ip a`, but br0 does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the one thing I kept overlooking was my firewall. The firewall was blocking my guests from being able to communicate across the bridge. I don't fully understand the problem, but I at least have an idea of what is going on thanks to this bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ufw/+bug/573461

So to fix the issue, I did this:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/default/ufw
```

And then change this

```
IPT_MODULES=""
```

to this

```
IPT_MODULES="bridge"
```

Then I go to this file:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/ufw/sysctl.conf
```

And append this to the end of it:

```
# Don't filter packets to our libvirt guests
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables = 0
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables = 0
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-arptables = 0
```

Then reload the firewall:

```
$ sudo ufw reload
```

Now my guests are fully able to access my network as if they were physical machines, while my host machine stays properly firewalled.

If someone has a 'for dummies' explanation of what exactly I'm doing here, please feel free to share. Best I can figure is that this tells UFW, even though it loads before the network config, to expect there to be bridges, and to not filter them. Or at least that's what I think it's doing.